# Partitioning tables in hive

Tags: mysql, hadoop, amazon-s3, mapreduce, hive

I am using Hive to load some text files from S3. Currently, the structure is as follows:

```
bucket/dir/id/text_files
```

The issue is that the `<id>` directory does not have the 'user=id' format that Hive seems to like for loading partitions. Typically, if the directory was bucket/dir/user=id, I could just do this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (
  data STRING
) PARTITIONED BY (user STRING)
LOCATION 'bucket/dir';
```

However, because I don't have the correct format for the partition directory, how would I go about doing the same thing, which is to say that I want to have a partition named user and make it equal to the id that is already in there?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Not sure about this, but it might work the way you specified it if you set the location explicitly when adding partitions, e.g. `ADD PARTITION (user='bla') LOCATION 'bucket/dir/bla';`

Comment: The issue is that I have a bunch of data pre-existing and would like to load it all in.

Comment: You will have to add the partitions anyway, the table definition alone will not suffice.

Comment: @LiMuBei is right, and adding the pre-existing data shouldn't be harder than creating a bash script

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is work for you.

```
load data inpath 'bucket/dir/user=id' overwrite into table table1 partition(user='id');
```